# What are good examples of questions that make college students think about chemistry concepts?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, redox

I am teaching the second semester of general chemistry at the college level. The course tends to get bogged down in calculations, and sometimes we forget about the big picture and what is going on at the atomic level. What are some good questions that would make students think deeply about the following topics:

- Intermolecular forces
- Kinetics of chemical reactions
- Equilibrium and direction of reactions
- Acid/base reactions
- Redox reactions (electrochemistry)

Comment: Perhaps this would be better on meta.

Comment: How do I move it to meta.

Comment: If it gets closed mod can do it if he agrees.

Comment: @Mithoron Meta is for `discussion, support and feature requests` for the site. Won't this post be better as a community wiki such as [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry).

Comment: @AvnishKabaj Thing is that's a list of links to other questions. Not unlike https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/the-giant-list-of-duplicates. Well, there were similar posts on main so I guess it may be better here, but I can't say it's particularly good fit for the site.

Comment: Well, it's something like https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37425/what-are-the-most-extreme-chemicals

Answer (score 1):

- Intermolecular forces

  [Are there contradictions about intermolecular forces in the postulates of kinetic theory?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97227/are-there-contradictions-about-intermolecular-forces-in-the-postulates-of-kineti/107750#107750)

  [Why do molecules having a higher relative molecular mass have stronger inter-molecular forces?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/why-do-molecules-having-a-higher-relative-molecular-mass-have-stronger-inter-mol)
- Kinetics of chemical reactions

  [Does a first order reaction really get completed only at infinity?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/11105/does-a-first-order-reaction-really-get-completed-only-at-infinity)
- Equilibrium and direction of reactions

  [What does it mean to shift equilibrium?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5486/what-does-it-mean-to-shift-equilibrium)

  [At equilibrium are the rates of the forward and backward reactions equal to zero?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63055/at-equilibrium-are-the-rates-of-the-forward-and-backward-reactions-equal-to-zero)
- Acid/base reactions

  [Is the behavior of a dilute strong acid the same as the behavior of a weak acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53429/is-the-behavior-of-a-dilute-strong-acid-the-same-as-the-behavior-of-a-weak-acid/53430#53430)
- Redox reactions (electrochemistry)

  [Why is it important to use a salt bridge in a voltaic cell? Can a wire be used?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/why-is-it-important-to-use-a-salt-bridge-in-a-voltaic-cell-can-a-wire-be-used)